# "one off payment" meaning

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning, phrase-meaning, definition

So I was talking with someone about some sponsorship which includes a starter package and it said that it would cost $50 and after said *one off payment*. So what does it mean? Like it will not be refundable or will be the only payment of will not count to something...?

Comment: Searching for [one off payment](http://www.bing.com/search?q=one%20off%20payment&form=OSDSRC) gives good results from dictionaries.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Nathan Tuggy mentions in his comment, a "one-off" is something than occurs once and only once, and is not part of a regular process or sequence.  A "one-off" payment would be something you make *once* for some particular charge or fee, and then in the future you might pay a regular fee every month or whatever.

For example, if you join a fitness club they may try to get you to pay a one-off "initiation fee" in addition to your monthly fee.  The initiation fee you would pay one time, and then you wouldn't have to pay for it again.

Or let's say I move into a new apartment and I want to hook up to my local cable company.  The cable company might charge a one-off "connection" fee in addition to my usual monthly charge for services.

The "one-off" doesn't mean the fee is or is not refundable, or what it will actually be used for.  It just means what it says, a *one-time* charge.  As with anything, you can (and probably should) negotiate.